# how to migrate InfopathForms to ms PowerApps Forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, task-list, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have a requirement to migrate InfoPath forms to Microsoft PowerApps forms and I am facing below issues in PowerApps forms.

Issues:

1. How to Integrate PowerApps forms for a SharePoint online task list.
2. PowerApps Forms should fit irrespective of the screen size of the device (Mobile, Tab, Desktop).

If anyone can share pointers in this regard, is highly appreciated.

**Note**: Moderators, Can you please mark it as a community based question. As my question doesn't contain any code.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form), Custom list and library templates are currently not supported; including but not limited to lists such as Announcements, Contacts and Tasks.

We could create a responsive layout to respond to different devices or window sizes via Disable Scale to fit.

Reference: [Create responsive layouts in canvas apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/create-responsive-layout#disable-scale-to-fit)